# Как сделать виджет абсолютно квадратным?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

я хочу чтобы этот виджет был максимально возможного размера но квадратным (тоесть если ему "доступна" прямоугольная область, то сторона квадрата - меньшая сторона прямоугольника)

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *


class FieldWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FieldWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_picture)
        self.bind(size=self.update_picture)
        self.update_picture()

    def update_picture(self, *args):
        self.canvas.clear()

        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```